# System dynamics in anylogic

Tags: anylogic, systemdynamics

I have a problem with anylogic program. I would like to implement a system dynamics problem where process works 8 hours a day beacause I want to simulate a factory timetable.
The time I've used in Model Time is day and not hour because I'm interested in day arrivals of my input.

Can the flows stop after 8 hours and restart the next day?
Thank for the help

I've tried to use a dynamic variable with a condition but I'm not sure about that

Answer (score 0):

this is where the multiple tools anylogic provides come in handy... there are about 100 different ways to do this, but I'll tell you one

from the agent palette take 2 events, both will have mode: cyclic  one runs the first time in 8 hours (Event A), the other runs the first time immediately (event B).

your dynamic variable called dv will be set to constant and in event A you will do:

```
dv=0;
```

in event B you will do

```
dv=1;
```

you will multiply dv with the formula inside the flows you want to stop

Another option is doing more or less the same thing using a schedule from the agent palette... but i will let you explore that on your own.